# ASP.NET Core MVC view cannot read from controller parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem adding goals to an existing match. The match is pre-created and is being modified. In the Create Goal view, the disabled input shows the ID received and it is an existing entity in the DB as shown below. The error message is:

SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_MatchEvent_Matches_MatchID". The conflict occurred in database "FootballManager1", table "dbo.Matches", column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated.

UPDATE: the problem seems to be the MatchEvent.ID field, which is 0. Goal is derived from MatchEvent and I added DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity to the ID field in the MatchEvent.cs

Matches view:

```
<div class="form-group col">
    <a asp-controller="Goals" asp-action="Create" asp-route-MatchID="@Model.ID" class="btn btn-success btn-block text-white">Add goal</a>
</div>
```

Goals controller Create methods:

```
// GET: Goals/Create
        public IActionResult Create(int matchId)
        {
            ViewData["MatchID"] = matchId;
            ViewData["PlayerID"] = new SelectList(_context.Players, "Id", "FullName");
            ViewData["AssisterID"] = new SelectList(_context.Players, "Id", "FullName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Goals/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int matchId, /*[Bind("AssisterID,ID,PlayerID,MatchID")]*/ Goal goal)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Match matchToUpdate = await _context.Matches.FindAsync(matchId);
                if (matchToUpdate == null) return NotFound();
                _context.Add(goal);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            ViewData["MatchID"] = matchId;
            ViewData["PlayerID"] = new SelectList(_context.Players, "Id", "FullName", goal.PlayerID);
            ViewData["AssisterID"] = new SelectList(_context.Players, "Id", "FullName", goal.AssisterID);
            return View(goal);
        }
```

Goals create view:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MatchID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MatchID" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.MatchID" disabled="disabled" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Player" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="PlayerID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PlayerID">
                    <option value="">-- Select scorer --</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AssisterID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="AssisterID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AssisterID">
                    <option value="">-- Select assister --</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Goal model:

```
public class Goal : MatchEvent
    {
        //FOREIGN KEY
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Assister))]
        public int? AssisterID { get; set; }

        //NAVIGATION PROPERTY
        public Player Assister { get; set; }
    }
```

MatchEvent class:

```
public abstract class MatchEvent
{
    //PRIMARY KEY
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //FOREIGN KEYS
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Player))]
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Match))]
    public int MatchID { get; set; }

    //NAVIGATION PROPERTIES
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    public Match Match { get; set; }
}
```

[Create goal UI preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6HMT.png)
[POST create state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epcCE.png)

I appreaciate all answers!

Comment: You don't seem to have associated the `goal` with the `matchID`. I don't see any way that the matchID would be added to the database. I assume it should be part of the goal object? It's hard because we can't see your class definitions

Comment: please post your class model.

Comment: Post updated. Yes, it is in the model class and is a required field. I think the problem is in the post create method or the input field value type, but it seems to be displayed correctly.

Comment: Hi @Mészáros Barnabás,Could you please share whole models?What is your Match model?It works well in my project,so I think you need provide more code.Besides,I saw your picture,matchId has value,but your input for MatchID is disabled.The disabled input can't be posted to the backend.How did you go that?

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying this hard. I think this is the easiest way, here are my models which are involved in the topic. https://files.fm/u/te3pdjxz5

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the `MatchID` property of the `Goal` object has values after you submit the form. If the `MatchID` property has a value, check whether there is an existing Match with the same `Id` as `MatchID` in your database, if the `MatchID` property is empty then check this part of your code

```
                <input asp-for="MatchID" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.MatchID" disabled="disabled" />
```

Maybe for some reason, the MatchID is not being posted back to the controller action. For example, try to remove the `disabled` attribute and see whether the id value will be posted to the controller action and bind to the `Goal` object. Another solution would be to replace this code block with this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MatchID)
```

Normally the users don't have to view the Ids of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is many to many relationships. I think your problem is navigating one another class property. for that, you found SQL Exception. You can try something like this:-

Your All Models:-

```
 public abstract class MatchEvent
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        //FOREIGN KEYS
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Player))]
        public int PlayerID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Match))]
        public int MatchID { get; set; }

        //NAVIGATION PROPERTIES
        public Player Player { get; set; }
        public Match Match { get; set; }
    }



    public class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        //Navigation Properties
        public List<MatchEvent> MatchEvents { get; set; }
    }


    public class Match
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        //Navigation Properties
        public List<MatchEvent> MatchEvents { get; set; }
    }



    public class Goal : MatchEvent
    {
        //FOREIGN KEY
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Assister))]
        public int? AssisterID { get; set; }

        //NAVIGATION PROPERTY
        public Player Assister { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the Many-to-Many sample:-

ApplicatinDbContext.cs

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelbuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelbuilder);
            modelbuilder.Entity<MatchEvent>()
            .HasOne(b => b.Player) 
            .WithMany(ba => ba.MatchEvents) 
            .HasForeignKey(bi => bi.PlayerID); 
                                             
          
            modelbuilder.Entity<MatchEvent>()
            .HasOne(b => b.Match)
            .WithMany(ba => ba.MatchEvents)
           .HasForeignKey(bi => bi.MatchID);
        }



        public DbSet<Player> players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Match> matches { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MatchEvent> matchEvents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Goal> goals { get; set; }
    }
```

I think your DbContext Class should change something like the above code. Hope it resolves this issue.